# Vuetify - how to disable Display Helpers in a custom build?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, vuetify-loader

Some of Vuetify's display helpers (https://vuetifyjs.com/en/styles/display/#display) collide with Tailwind classes.
In Bootstrap, fore example, there's a way to disable (=not include) utility classes in a custom build.
Searched in the docs and in `vuetify-loader`'s docs for a way to do it, couldn't find one - is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

I found this [article](https://medium.com/@pierremriau/how-to-replace-vuetify-utility-classes-with-tailwindcss-9a3ebaa21f4f) that helped me remove some of the Display helpers (utility classes) from Vuetify. Over [here](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/blob/master/packages/vuetify/src/styles/settings/_utilities.scss) you can see all the available utilities you can disable.

Answer (score 1):

In **Vuetify 3**, remove this line, which is proably somewhere near your `createVuetify()`:

```js
import "vuetify/styles";
```

add these in a .scss file: (they're needed so Vuetify's components render properly)

```scss
@use "vuetify/lib/styles/generic";
@use "vuetify/lib/styles/elements";
```

and remember to import that scss file in `main.js`

```js
import "main.scss";
```

---

**explanation**

if you read `vuetify/styles/main.scss`, currently, you'll see this:

```scss
@forward './settings'
@use './generic'
@use './elements'
@use './utilities'
```

I just guessed that if I omitted `utilities` that, well, the utilities would be omitted.

Answer (score 0):

While I'm not aware of any way to disable Vuetify's Display Helpers, it is possible to prevent collision by prefixing Tailwind's classes. You can read about it in [this thread](https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss/issues/465) on Tailwind's GitHub.